# What is the proper way to identify the data type of columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I'm currently working on a project where I need to transform the data in a pandas dataframe to another representation that uses a different (non-python) type system. The transformation is not covered by one of pandas' [serialization/io methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html#serialization-io-conversion). In particular I need to map the pandas dataframe column data types to those of the other type system. For starters, let's assume the target type system to be pretty simple having only `string`, `integer`, `float`, `boolean`, and `timestamp` types.

So, I started by looking at the [dataframe dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/basics.html#dtypes) with a simple example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

headers = ["string", "integer", "float", "boolean", "timestamp"]
data = [["a", 1, 1.0, True, datetime.now()]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
dts = df.dtypes

for col in dts.index:
  print("column: ", col, " - type: ", dts[col].name)
```

which gave me:

```
column:  string  - type:  object
column:  integer  - type:  int64
column:  float  - type:  float64
column:  boolean  - type:  bool
column:  timestamp  - type:  datetime64[ns]
```

Okay, getting `object` for string columns is not nice so I found the [`Dataframe.convert_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) method which, when added to the dataframe creation line gave me:

```
column:  string  - type:  string
column:  integer  - type:  Int64
column:  float  - type:  Int64
column:  boolean  - type:  boolean
column:  timestamp  - type:  datetime64[ns]
```

Better for my string column, but now I'm getting `Int64` (with a capital "I") for both my integer and float columns (!) and `boolean` instead of `bool`. (Okay, I'm back to `float64` when I use a "real" float such as "0.1" in the example data but still...)

That made me wonder whether I'm on the right track with this approach. I then looked at the [numpy dtype documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html) and the [numpy dtype charcodes](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-built-in). But there doesn't seem to be a charcode for every possible data type, esp. not for string types. Also, pandas' extension dtypes that I get after applying `convert_dtypes()` don't have the `char` attribute anymore.

So my question is, what is the canonical way to obtain data type identifiers for the columns in a pandas dataframe that I can use for mapping those data types to another type system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.dtypes` **is** the canonical way to obtain data type identifiers. You can print for each `dtype` the associated underlying numpy dtype code with `<dtype>.str`. You can also get the kind (integer, float, ...) with `<dtype>.kind`:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

headers = ["string", "integer", "float", "boolean", "timestamp"]
data = [["a", 1, 1.0, True, datetime.now()]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)

dts = df.dtypes
for index, value in dts.items():
    print("column %s dtype[class: %s; name: %s; code: %s; kind: %s]" % (index, type(value), value.name, value.str, value.kind))
```

yields:

```
column string dtype[class: <class 'numpy.dtype'>; name: object; code: |O; kind: O]
column integer dtype[class: <class 'numpy.dtype'>; name: int64; code: <i8; kind: i]
column float dtype[class: <class 'numpy.dtype'>; name: float64; code: <f8; kind: f]
column boolean dtype[class: <class 'numpy.dtype'>; name: bool; code: |b1; kind: b]
column timestamp dtype[class: <class 'numpy.dtype'>; name: datetime64[ns]; code: <M8[ns]; kind: M]
```

The issue is that some datatypes are defined specifically in pandas as you noted, but they are backed by numpy datatypes (they have numpy datatype codes). For example, `numpy` defines the `datetime64[ns]` that you can see above, but pandas defines a *timezone-localized* dtype on top of it. You can see it :

```
# localize with timezone
df['timestamp'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['timestamp']).tz_localize(tz='UTC')

# look at the dtype of timestamp: now a pandas dtype
index, value = 'timestamp', df.dtypes.timestamp
print("column %s dtype[class: %s; name: %s; code: %s; kind: %s]" % (index, type(value), value.name, value.str, value.kind))
```

yields

```
column timestamp dtype[class: <class 'pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes.DatetimeTZDtype'>; name: datetime64[ns, UTC]; code: |M8[ns]; kind: M]
```

Now the dtype *class* is a custom pandas class (`DatetimeTZDtype`), while the underlying dtype code is a numpy one. The same would go if you use `string` datatypes, that are not in numpy by default.

So to sum-up, to reach your original goal, you should first look at the `type(<dtype>)` and if it is not a custom pandas one, then to look at the numpy `<dtype>.kind` (It is preferrable to `<dtype>.str` as numpy allows you to define *many* kind of integers (big/little endian, nb of bits, etc.)).

Finally as you found out, [`Dataframe.convert_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) is a converter, and it has parameters to select which auto-conversion feature to turn on/off.

Comment: Thanks @smarie, for the exhaustive answer! I guess I'll go for the `<dtype>.kind` then. Just a follow-up question about strings: For those I get kind `O` (same for date and time columns, with e.g. `date.today()` or `time(17,5,31)`). How can I safely identify string columns and separate them from date and time columns (which should be mapped to the `timestamp` type in my assumed simple target type system). Seems like I do need to apply `convert_dtypes()` for that?

Comment: As mentioned in my post (I edited the last bits for clarity), you should *first* read the `type(<dtype>)` to determine if this is a pandas type (string, etc.) and *then* look at the `<dtype>.kind`. You are right that to be able to *infer* that some objects are string dtypes you should try `convert_dtypes()`. I expect that some day pandas will also provide such a thing for date and time as you mention.